# How to use Wordpress image sizes with Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I have an acf repeater containing images. I am only grabbing the first row in the repeater as I only want to display that image. But I also want to set its size to the default large image size that WordPress automatically creates I have tried a couple solutions but I think I'm getting the syntax wrong. Can you show me?

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
    $floorplans = get_field('floorplans'); 
    $img = $floorplans[0]['floorplan'];
    ?>

<img src="<?php echo $img['url']; ?>" alt="">
```

Comment: You have all the sizes inside your `$img` - you can var dump them to see it : `var_dump($img);` will show you the entire object

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's what I did to achieve this;

```
<?php
    $floorplans = get_field('floorplans'); //gets the field
    $first_row = $floorplans[0]; //first row of field
    $img = $first_row['floorplan']; //gets the repeater field 
    $img_lrg = $img['sizes']['large']; //applies the size I want the image to be
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to receive large image of acf field

```
$img=get_sub_field('floorplans');

<img src="<?php echo $img['sizes']['large']; ?>" alt="">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code to fetch image with respective sizes via Advanced custom fields.

```
$floorplans = get_field('floorplans'); 

$thumbnail_img = $floorplans['sizes']['thumbnail'];
$medium_img = $floorplans['sizes']['medium'];
$large_img = $floorplans['sizes']['large'];

<img src="<?php echo $large_img; ?>" alt="">
```

Comment: Best answer so far, thanks. But I only want the first image inside floorplans. How can I get only the first image and apply the large size to it?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks